# Recursively get members of an AD group

Tags: recursion, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The MS Graph API has the possibility to list the **direct** members of an AD group using

[/groups/{id}/members](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members)

Is there a way to get both direct and **indirect** members, i.e. member of members of members and so on and so forth.

I would like to avoid the need to implement some recursive logic on the client if it can be done another way, possibly through the use of OData query parameters?

I have tried the following using $expand and $level, but unfortunately the 'members' navigation property doesn't exist on the child groups for some reason and I guess that's why they are not expanded.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('{group-id}')?$expand=members($levels=max)
```

Unrelated to the question, could someone with the necessary SO permissions please make the ms-graph and the microsoftgraph tags synonyms?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: The feature request mentioned below is [in beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-beta) now.

I found a [feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/20314399-get-all-members-of-a-group-including-nested-group) on uservoice.com for this, so it seems like it does not exist yet. If you came here looking for the solution, I encourage you to go and [vote for the feature](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/20314399-get-all-members-of-a-group-including-nested-group).